# Bugs with Total Amount,Wrong Calculation & format

Tags: android, formatting, calculation

May I know what's the problem with this? It should be "5555555556" instead. See the Total Amount is Not CORRECT.

[image]

**Is My Code wrote wrong already?
Here is my CODE**

```
//show total amount
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = mSQLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM (Amount) from Donation_Details WHERE strftime('%d %m %Y',CreatedDate) = strftime('%d %m %Y',date('now'))", null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                int sum = cursor.getInt(0);
                DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
                String yourFormattedString = formatter.format(sum);

                total_Amount.setText("RM " + yourFormattedString);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And It can't show Decimal if I wrote "555555.55". It will only show infront numbers. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `int` to `double` of sum variable and also change `DecimalFormat` like below code,

```
try {
    SQLiteDatabase db = mSQLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM (Amount) from Donation_Details WHERE strftime('%d %m %Y',CreatedDate) = strftime('%d %m %Y',date('now'))", null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        double sum = cursor.getDouble(0);
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,###.00");
        String yourFormattedString = formatter.format(sum);
        total_Amount.setText("RM " + yourFormattedString);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Put `#,###,###,###.00` in Format

Comment: Great! Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to change

```
int
```

to

```
double
```

and change your decimal format to

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,###");
```

Comment: You should probably mention the `DecimalFormat` too